# Are @ManyToOne indexed by default

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Are `@ManyToOne` indexed by default?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseAudit implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "userList" })
    private Reg reg;
}
```

In my `H2` DB, it is creating an index, but in my `Postgres`, it doesn't. Only the PK gets created as Index.

My Local settings:

```
jpa:
    database-platform: tech.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
```

My UAT settings:

```
jpa:
    database-platform: tech.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL10Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend on JPA but on the databases themselves.

When adding a foreign key, [H2 creates indexes automatically](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_table_add_constraint):

> The required indexes are automatically created if they don't exist yet.

But [PostgreSQL doesn't](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> Because [...] there are many choices available on how to index, declaration of a foreign key constraint does not automatically create an index on the referencing columns.

Comment: I foreign key is a reference to a primary key which is always indexed. How can it not be indexed?

Comment: @K.Nicholas It's well explained on the docs I shared, but to summarise: "Because [...] there are many choices available on how to index, declaration of a foreign key constraint does not automatically create an index on the referencing columns".

Comment: Perhaps, but JPA will choose one, and I figure one must be chosen. Ergo, foreign keys are indexed.

Comment: so FK is indexed by default? even though I do not see it on my table "indexes"

Comment: @K.Nicholas JPA (or at least Hibernate) won't explicitly create an index, it will just create the FK (see the generated SQL on [this documented example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-columns-unique-constraint), `book.author_id`).

Comment: @sophie As I said in my answer, it depends on the database: you'll get an index on your FKs with H2 and MySQL (and probably others), but not with PostgreSQL (and probably others).

Comment: @sophie It's usually a good idea to _not_ let JPA generate your DDL though anyway, you could have a look at tools like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) to be in control of the schema.

Comment: okay thanks @sp00m, was confused by K. Nicholas answer that FK are indexed. I tried to add `@Index` on my entity, but the generated changelog (through liquibase) doesn't contain the FK index also.

Comment: @K.Nicholas why is it redundant? I am always query-ing the `reg.id` on my User class. that is why i want to create a `reg_id` FK index.

Comment: The database will handle it for you. Check the query and execution plans.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I think I see where the confusion comes from: a foreign key is just a _constraint_ that ensures referential integrity. Also, if you're used to MySQL, you might see _key_ and _index_ as synonyms, but they are not fundamentally: indexes are a performance optimisation for a quick lookup. Keys do not technically need to be indexed, even PKs don't technically need to. All the databases I'm aware automatically index PKs though, and most databases automatically index FKs' _referencing_ columns too, but not PostgreSQL. But yeah, checking the execution plans is always the ultimate judge.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. I always preach watching the logs, checking the database, etc, etc. I would not have expected any foreign key indexes to be made since I don't see them in the SQL statements and I was thinking that database engine was able to use the PK index, but I guess it isn't really the same. I tried this out on MySQL and I see (and read) that MySQL creates an index on a FK in additional to the PK index. It does this on it's own because it thinks it is a good idea. Sorry for  the confusion and rude comments.